# Access to the collection in SSIS Foreach Loop

Tags: loops, collections, foreach, ssis

Does anyone know if there's a way to programmatically access the entire Item Collection in the Enumerator Configuration window of a Foreach Loop in SSIS 2008 R2?  I'm trying to query the entire item collection and determine which line items have specific flags, and then feed them into a parameter of a stored proc.

For example,

In my Foreach Loop, I have Foreach Item Enumerator items:

```
Column0   Column1   Column2
A         1         True
B         2         False
C         3         False
```

I have them lined up with variables Var0, Var1, Var2.

I need to be able to pass value "1" from the first line where Column2 = False.  Thanks!

Comment: You have a set of data in an SSIS Variable. You're shredding that data with a Foreach Loop Container. (here's where I get confused) The A row goes through fine. The B row, since there's a false in the third column, should lookup back to the entire dataset to find a valid value (1)?

Comment: Answered my own question ... in order to only iterate through certain values based on their boolean flags, I had to set the precedent condition by clicking on the green arrow.  In the next screen, I set "Variable AND precedence", which would only allow the package to continue if both 1) the variable was TRUE and 2) previous task completed.